# How to send only specified fields? (Not all fields in the page!)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I've created a account page that does accounting like login, register, activate etc. We've multiple forms in this page (login/register..) and we're performing multiple operations. Also, login fields are 'lUsername' and 'lPassword', register fields are 'rUsername', 'rPassword', 'rConfirmPassword' (...).

I want to send only 'lUsername' and 'lPassword' fields for login operation but I see form posting all fields to server (to execute). This is the normal operation for Asp.Net because all (runat="server") asp components/scripts running/executing on server.

I wonder how to send only specified fields in Asp.Net page? I think this is not possible with Asp.Net page itself because it must have only "one" main form (because of ecosystem).

Now, should I use a Javascript? Or what's the solution?

*(Namely I don't want to send "all" fields to server with GET/POST requests. I just want to send only specified fields about operation.)*

***+Additional:*** I know, we can do it with multiple forms in HTML. Create 3 different forms like `<form>` Login `</form>`, `<form>` Register `</form>` and `<form>` Activate `</form>`. **My implementation with Asp.Net (with different field names) already works but this is about 'not sending all fields' to server because they are unnecessary.**

What's the trick? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this is a wrong approach to incorborate multi operations inside one page.
if you must do it this way, here are my suggestions:

1- wrap all related controls inside their own `<Form>` tag (ex: `<form id="Register"...></form>`, `<form id="Login" ...> </form>` )

2- No need to stick with he same names for similar controls, change the name to be more descriptive (ex: txtRegUsername, txtLoginUsername) it costs nothing but make it easier for you to debug.

3- split forms inside partialviews (or user controls fi you are using webforms) so each form will have it's own logic/validation inside a single resource

4- finally, start with one simple form, and add the 2nd one then verify, and after you adjust them well enough, add the 3rd, 4th, etc

again, I recommend you to separate things to streamline your way, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Javascript to implement Ajax. However, most probably your application is incorrectly structured. You should not need to have selective fields of a form to be submitted